# How do we know that the vibrational eigenmodes of a system are able to fully describe all possible motions of the system?

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, vibrations, phonons, coupled-oscillators

In the classical case of identical masses coupled with springs, in a 3D lattice like structure. The equations of motion with the harmonic approximation are given by:

$$M\ddot{u}_{m}^{\alpha} = \sum_{n} \sum_{\beta = x,y,z} \left.\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial r_{m}^{\alpha} \partial r_{n}^{\beta}}\right\rvert_{\textbf{r}_{i} = \textbf{R}_{i}} u_{n}^{\beta} \hat{\textbf{e}}_{\beta}$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are spatial indexes, $n$ and $m$ are particle indexes. And $\textbf{R}_n$ is the equilibrium position of the $n^{th}$ mass. For this example we can make the further approximation,

$$U = \frac{K}{2}\sum_{n}(\textbf{u}_{n} - \textbf{u}_{n+1})^2 + cte.$$

where $K$ is the spring constant of the springs.

In solving this set of coupled differential equations, we tend to use the wave ansatz for $\textbf{u}_{n} \propto e^{i(\textbf{k}\cdot\textbf{R}_{n} -\omega t)}\hat{\textbf{n}}$. Where $\textbf{k}$, $\omega$ and $\hat{\textbf{n}}$ are the wavevector, circular frequency of oscillation, and the direction of oscillation respectively.

Doing imposes a constraint in the solution. In that we derive eigenfrequencies of the oscillation, and their corresponding eigenmodes of oscillation. The general solution of the problem is the superposition of all eigenmodes, in which all masses oscillate with the same wavevector $\textbf{k}$ and circular frequency $\omega$.

How do we know that the eigenmodes alone are able to fully describe every possible vibrational motion of the system?

Comment: I bet there is some uniqueness theorem.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory.

Answer (score -2):

Well it would not. In a purely random system every value is an eigenvalue and thus there are no eignevalues. If the system follows laws then these laws will cause edge conditions which will bound the system and eignevalues will describe all laws.